# Apache/Docusign - Restrict location by host or ip

Tags: apache-http-server

I'm trying to restrict an url called by Docusign event when a document is completed. I want to only give access to this url by Docusign host or ip but i'm unable to do so because of my limited skills on Apache. By following this documentation https://www.docusign.com/trust/security/esignature

I've tried to add this line in my vhost :

```
<LocationMatch "^/souscription/api/[^/].*/callback/.*$">
    Require host docusign.com docusign.net
</LocationMatch>
```

But I have this error in apache log:

```
[Wed Jul 29 12:59:09.663648 2020] [authz_host:error] [pid 32671] [client 162.248.186.11:50836] AH01753: access check of 'docusign.com docusign.net' to /souscription/api/1.0/callback/118/completed failed, reason: unable to get the remote host name
```

What's wrong with my config ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that the Require statement you specified requires Apache to reverse lookup the IP to get a hostname. This might not work in any case, as it is the case in your example - this IP does not have a reverse resolution. This results in the message you cited.

Somehow I doubt whether this is what you want anyway. If you really want to grant access based on client IP, you can something like this:

```
Require ip 10.1.0.0/16
```

You can find this and similar stuff in the official documentation from Apache: [Apache require documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/de/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require)

But please be aware that this type of access restriction could actually turn out to be rather ineffective and/or weak. If ever you can, I would recommend to replace it by something stronger (e.g. SSL client cert, or even username/password).

Comment: Finally, I will use hmac security as you advise. https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/connect-hmac